# Linux print column entries if entries for another column are equal

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Using linux commands or bash, how can print the entries for column 6 as a single line when the corresponding entries for column 3 are the same value. e.g. in the sample file below, when column 3 has the value of 1 (rows 1 and 2) print '4 103', when column 3 takes the value of 2 (rows 3 and 4) print '113 4', and such on.

```
1  A  1  C  18   4
1  A  1  C  8    103
1  A  2  C  3    113
1  A  2  C  50   4
1  A  3  C  2    103
1  A  3  C  33   4
1  A  3  C  9    4
1  A  3  C  113  103
1  A  4  C  44   203
```

The expected output should be:

```
4 103 
113 4
103 4 4 103 
203
```

I have tried using awk for selecting the rows when column 3 takes a specific value (i.e. when column 3 is 1 only), but I cannot find a way to achieve this when column 3 can take any integer value. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Sadly Stack Overflow is not a coding service. We ask users to show their attempts or research. This helps in providing an educational answer to the user. Currently, a plethora of solutions in various languages can be provided. From all these answers, none might be helpful if the user is not familiar with the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{last=1}
    $3 == last{printf "%d ", $6;last=$3;next}
    {last=$3; printf "\n%d ", $6}
    END{print ""}
' file
```

##### Output

```
4 103 
113 4 
103 4 4 103 
203
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a more C style answer then:

```
awk '{ if($3 != last) {last = $3; printf("\n%d ", $6)}
       else {printf("%d ", $6)}} 
     END {print ""}
    ' file
```

You don't need to initialize `last` because numbers always initialize from 0 in awk. Note that if 3rd column on first line is not 0 then this will start with printing a blankline first, then rest of the stuff.

So output will be:

```
4 103
113 4
103 4 4 103
203
```